# How to find name of the command locally

Tags: command-line, man

I use Linux not Windows for several years at home and consider using command line quicker way to do things.  However sometimes I could not easily recall name of needed command, for example instead of `adduser` I try to use `mkuser` in analogy to `mkdir`,  `chperm` in analogy to `chown`.  I remember in MS Office in help pages in `see also/related` there were usually several other topics close to it and I was able to find what I needed if I could recall related topic. In Linux man pages `see also` is very short,  e.g. for `chown` it's `chown (2)` only.  Before Internet was widespread,  how do you find name of the needed program?

Answer (score 2):

The traditional command for this is `apropos`

For example, to search sections 1 *Executable programs or shell commands* and 8 *System administration commands* of the manual for terms `add` and `user`:

```
$ apropos -s1,8 add -a user
addgroup (8)         - add a user or group to the system
adduser (8)          - add a user or group to the system
h5jam (1)            - Add a user block to a HDF5 file
pam_issue (8)        - PAM module to add issue file to user prompt
useradd (8)          - create a new user or update default new user information
```

Answer (score 2):

The `apropos` command will do what you need. You use it with a regular expression. For example, in your case, you can use:

```
apropos mk

apropos user
```

It will return all of the commands with those strings which will include `mkuser`.

If you were looking for the command that changes or lists attributes but couldn't quite remember the command then you could use:

```
apropos attr
```

That would return `chattr` and `lsattr` and anything else containing that string.

Answer (score 2):

As others have answered, `apropos` is the answer. For people who have difficulty getting the spelling correct, or who like shorter command, this is also available as

```
man -k
```